# I can not write data from the Firebase Cloud Functions in Firebase Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

How several days ago I started using Firebase Cloud Functions and I can not write data to the database.
Could you help me.
Thanks in advance.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.userCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    let userId = event.data.uid;
    let userName = event.data.displayName;

    admin.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .set({
        name: userName,
        city: "",
        rating: 0
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please [see the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions) to understand how Cloud Functions works with async code.

You're not returning a promise from your function.  If your function performs any async work that yields a promise, you have to indicate to Cloud Functions wait for that work to complete by returning a promise that resolves when the work is complete:

```
exports.userCreated = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {
    let userId = event.data.uid;
    let userName = event.data.displayName;

    return admin.firestore()
    .collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .set({
        name: userName,
        city: "",
        rating: 0
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much